# Fail2ban custom regular expresion

Tags: linux, server, fail2ban

Trying to add custom rule on regular expression in order to block the below log.

```
Mar 17 18:46:52 s21409974 named[1577]: client @0x7g246c107030 1.1.1.1#8523 (.): query (cache) './ANY/IN' denied
```

I did tried with online tools like this one (https://www.regextester.com) but on the fail2ban-regex  test command does display like it miss it.
Any suggestion about the rule or about how to better troubleshoot?
Thank in advance

Comment: And what does your regex look like?

Comment: What is/are the criteria for what you want to filter out within that log line?

Comment: I want to query this:
==== 1.1.1.1#8523 (.): query (cache) './ANY/IN' denied ====

where 1.1.1.1 is the attacker ip i want to ban.
Even if i do simple:
==== 1.1.1.1#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]  ====

Doe miss it

Comment: And what does your regex look like? Please edit your question accordingly ...

Comment: 1.1.1.1 is *not* an attacker, btw, it's one of the biggest DNS servers out and about, it's owned by cloudflare.  There's a chance that someone else is querying random hostnames on your domain and using 1.1.1.1 as their name server. Blocking it doesn't sound like a wise move, though.

Comment: Look at the last paragraph in [this accepted answer on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/1049521/140149) ... I share the views expressed therein =}

Comment: Guys the 1.1.1.1 is just an example i did added, instead of the real ips, so 1.1.1.1 is just an example, i could also used 2.2.2.2 or 3.3.3.3 .

Comment: The real question, though, is whether there is a justified interest in trying to find DNS entries from any of those; you *don't* want to run a **DDoS by security feature** against your own domain, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to write a custom regex? 
This message is pretty well matching with original fail2ban filter [named-refused](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/filter.d/named-refused.conf):

```sh
$ msg="Mar 17 18:46:52 s21409974 named[1577]: client @0x7g246c107030 1.1.1.1#8523 (.): query (cache) './ANY/IN' denied"
$ fail2ban-regex "$msg" named-refused

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : named-refused
Use      single line : Mar 17 18:46:52 s21409974 named[1577]: client @0x7...


Results
=======

Prefregex: 1 total
|  ^(?:\s*\S+ (?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+\(?named(?:\(\S+\))?\)?:?|\(?named(?:\(\S+\))?\)?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)\s+)?(?: error:)?\s*client(?: @\S*)? (?:\[?(?:(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<ip4>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})|(?P<ip6>(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}::?|::){1,7}(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|(?<=:):)))\]?|(?P<dns>[\w\-.^_]*\w))#\S+(?: \([\S.]+\))?: (?P<content>.+)\s(?:denied|\(NOTAUTH\))\s*$
`-

Failregex: 1 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1] ^(?:view (?:internal|external): )?query(?: \(cache\))?
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]
```

But if you need it, here you go (regex interpolated from fail2ban's pref- & failregex):

```regex
^\s*\S+\s+named\[\d+\]: client(?: @\S*)? <ADDR>#\S+(?: \([\S.]+\))?: (?:view (?:internal|external): )?query(?: \(cache\))? '[^']+' denied
```

replace `<ADDR>` with `<HOST>` if your fail2ban version is smaller than 0.10.